# Unable to get rid of beeping sound from 2021 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

My 2021 MacBook Pro (18,3) recently started making a strange beeping sound. I would like to know its source since the sound makes me somewhat concerned and is also quite irritating. I’m running macOS 12.6.3. I’ve characterised the beeping below:

- I made [a short recording of the beeping](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/nu1t1nbh790zagkthykqt/beeping.m4a?rlkey=9xesbhrbi6eu32wf0fir6hwv6&dl=0).
- Attaching headphones or adjusting volume have no effect, i.e. the beeping can still be heard. (I’m not even completely sure if the speakers are the source.)
- The beeping stops sometimes even for a long time but so far has resumed later.
- The beeping starts again after reboot.
- [SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) doesn’t list any applications that produce audio output.
- The beeping happens even in the login window but (so far) not in Safari launched by a guest user.
- I tried uninstalling the Teams audio driver and stopping Adobe’s processes but these didn’t seem to have any effect.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: are you sharing your Mac with other users

Comment: No, I’m not. I proceeded to uninstall Zoom as well; we'll see if that has any effect.

Comment: did you say you still hear it if you mute the speakers

Comment: It is a Alert sound, but we do not know who it is, to check go to System Preferences > Sound and change the alert sound, to confirm it is a Alert

Comment: @Ruskes Yeah, neither muting, otherwise changing the output volume nor changing the output device helps. I went through the alert sounds but none of them matches the one I’m getting.

Comment: OK, start in Safe mode by turning the power off/on and holding the Shift, that will turn off all non Apple software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various other options, I noticed that the sound can be heard even when starting up in recovery mode. A colleague suggested that the MacBook might be trying to start its fan. I installed [Macs Fan Control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) and, lo and behold, the RPM of the left side fan indeed alternates between zero and some 26k. I guess I’ll have to try my luck with Apple’s repair service.